# Java File Not Found but in same directory and with caught exceptions

Tags: java, file-io, io, bufferedreader

Okay this is weird and ridiculous..

I have this really simple code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
      String s;
      while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
      }
    }
```

I also tried wrapping the `BufferedReader...` in a try-catch block. Why the heck is this throwing this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /input.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
```

It is thrown at the `BufferedReader` line.

The file is in the same package / directory as the java file. I have tried both declaring a throws Exception and try-catch blocks.

Whatever I do I keep getting this error.

Comment: `The file is in the same package / directory as the java file.`. Your expectations are wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the file in the working directory from which Java is started. Depending on how you start the program, this could be different.

You can print the current working directory with:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to access any resources from package by using  `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path");`

Example:

```
InputStream inputstreamFromPackage = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("<packageName/file.ext>");
```